# How to add a classname to the 3 Active/Visible/Shown Slides in SwiperJS

Tags: css, next.js, slider, carousel, swiper.js

So basically I have a carousel with `slidesPerView={3}` in **Swiper**. and I want to style the sliders that are not shown, so I want to either add a className to the visible sliders or I would add a className to the not visible sliders. There are multiple attempts I did which are:

adding this: `slideActiveClass="swiper-slide-active"` and I noticed that in the documentation, it wasn't compatible with react which means it isn't compatible with nextjs aswell. But then I saw in the inspect mode that the active class is there even if I didnt added `slideActiveClass="swiper-slide-active"` so I made the CSS style like this:

```
.swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active) {
    ...
}
```

but the problem was that it was only styling the first shown slider not the three shown sliders.

So another attempt was by adding this: `slideVisibleClass='swiper-slide-visible'` which also was unfortunately not compatible with react and nextjs. Though I did checked the inspect mode/dev tools and the className wasn't there unlike the active class.

The last attempt I did was adding this: `slidesPerGroup={3}` thinking that it would group there 3 sliders and make them all active classes. But it didn't work, what it made was to make the next slide not by 1 but by 3 slides each next slide.

I tried searching too but couldn't find any more clues.

- "swiper": "^8.4.2"
- "next": "12.3.0",
- "react": "18.2.0",

Comment: Have you had a good look using your browser's devtools inspect facility to find out just why your first attempt was not touching the other sliders?

Comment: so apparently i saw the reason in github. 
*And it won't have active class because active class depends on swiper position. If position not changed, then no class will be changed.*

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/1677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now (`slideVisibleClass` Not supported in Swiper Angular/React/Svelte/Vue). The most simple solution is to use simple logic (Of course this is not flex).

In general for 3 slides per view (Without center mode).
This slides are visible:

**[1_active][2_next][3_last]**[4][5][6]

1_active:

```
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active
```

2_next

```
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next
```

3. `3_last`: [`+` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) select slide placed immediately after 2

```
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next + .swiper-slide
```